# What does 'Forward Isolation vs. Frequency' curve in Op Amp Datasheet mean?

Tags: operational-amplifier, isolation, frequency-response

I am looking at [this ADA4806 datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4806-1.pdf). The specific curve I am looking at it as below. I dont understand what is 'ISOLATION (dB)' on the Y-axis. What is it? What does this curve mean?

[image]

Comment: What it's telling you is that at 10MHz, there is enough parasitic conductance through and around the IC, that it only provides about 20dB of isolation from input to output when shut down. So, with a 10MHz 0.5V input signal, you'll see about 50mv on the output under the test conditions (RL = 2K).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolation is referring to the output impedance of your multi-mode op-amp when in /SHUTDOWN mode. See the data sheet text below.

I'm afraid you can search the same data sheet for the word 'isolation' and find the below text, so I haven't found anything you couldn't have.

[image]